# fit images in a row ionic with padding and margins

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I need 4 images to fit in a row with comfortable margins in ionic so I used col-25 for it, However, images look quite contrived with no margins. How can I have my images adapt to the div size available with required margins?

I tried using col-20 grid and in that case images overlap with each other.Using col-33 renders images with pretty good padding and margins but fit in 3 images in a screen as expected.
Demo:

http://play.ionic.io/app/5a918b3bb92f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width of the image to 100%

```
img {width:100%};
```

Check http://play.ionic.io/app/991572fd1202

Comment: Hi, Thanks, It worked. Do you mind stating the reason?

Comment: It makes the image responsive, so it will adjust to the width of the container.